# How to enable a text box depending on radio button groups by vba in word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the following activex controls in a VBA UserForm:

```
1.  Radio Button Group: Name: radioGender
a) radio button: Female> Group Name: radioGender, Name: radioFemale, value=True
b) radio button: Male> Group Name: radioGender, Name: radioMale, value=False
2. Text box: Name: TextBox1
```

If the user selects the radio button `radioFemale`, then `Textbox1` should be enabled, otherwise `Textbox1` should be disabled.

I can get `TextBox1` enabled if set a code on click of `radioFemale` and `radioMale` Option buttons separately:

```
Private Sub radioFemale_Click()
  TextBox1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub radioMale_Click()
  TextBox1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

But instead of coding on each radio button individually I'd like code for the radio button group `radioGender`, so that based on the selected value of radio button group, `TextBox1` can be enabled/disabled.

What should be the vba code in this case? Please note that I have activex radiobuttons in a VBA UserForm.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's 2018, your radio button group is missing `[ ] NotYourBusiness` ;-) ...that said, have you tried handling the button's `Change` event and researched what code you would write to programmatically access `TextBox1` and set its `.Enabled` property to `True` or `False` depending on the state of the radio button?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon coulfd not understand your comment. Name of my radio button group is: radioGender

Comment: @Cindy Meister, My question is updated with screen shot of radio button,  group in properties of Female radio button and ms word version. You can see, In form, it is an radio button, although it is stated as option button. Please try to solve my problem if you can. Thanks

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?62991-How-to-enable-a-text-box-depending-on-radio-button-groups-by-vba-in-word
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184